# How do I programmatically add a statusbar to an WPF Window application using C#

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, statusbar, wpf-4.0

I understand System.Windows.Form.StatusBar is not available in VisualStudio 2010.
What will be a preferable control? From what library?  Any example?

Comment: Are you going to select an answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.statusbar.aspx

Heres how to use Statusbars in WPF. Learning XAML will really help you even if it is a bit tedious.